# When is a subtenant entitled to have their security deposit returned?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, deposits, new-york

Halfway through last year, I subleased my apartment unit and moved to a new location.  I received a security deposit equal to the monthly rate paid by my subtenant.  My rental company has informed me that their security deposit return policy - as per New York State law - is to return the deposit (minus applicable cleaning or maintenance fees) within 30 days of the end of the lease.

My question is: am I, the sublessor, bound by the same legal statute, even though I am not the property's owner or active manager?

In other words: is it be legal to wait until I have received my security deposit from the landlord before I return my subtenant's deposit, assuming it all occurs within the 30 day period?

Comment: Try on the Law area? It's out of scope here.

Comment: Duplicated the question there.  Asked here since there seemed to be more answers regarding deposits.  Thank you for the note.

Comment: is there a signed contract?

Comment: Yes, but I do not have access to it at the moment, and I am not sure if these terms in particular were defined.

Comment: I think the answer is going to depend on the exact wording of the sublet agreement, subject to local law... I recommend asking a lawyer in your area.

Comment: Don't mess with tenant protections, especially not in New York.